# UniData Concatinate in SELECT

Tags: universe, unidata, uniquery

I need to search on the concatenated data in UniData using UniQuery. what are my options?

Something like below:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.DETAILS WITH (FIRSTNAME:LASTNAME) = "????"
```

Basically below is search criteria:
FIRSTNAME + LASTNAME = ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using EVAL to run a temporary expression in your query:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.DETAILS WITH EVAL "FIRSTNAME : LASTNAME" = "????"
```

I found [this blog post](http://mvdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/06/your-friendly-unidata.html) with other examples of EVAL as well

Comment: BTW EVAL can also be used in UniVerseSQL but not directly in the WHERE clause. You must alias the result of EVAL in the SELECT and then use the alias in the WHERE clause.